# Unable to get textures to work in OpenGL in Common Lisp

Tags: opengl, lisp, common-lisp, textures, sdl

I am building a [simple Solar system model](https://github.com/monomon/planetarium) and trying to set textures on some spheres.

The geometry is properly generated, and I tried a couple different ways to generate the texture coordinates. At present I am relying on `glu:quadric-texture` for generating the coordinates when `glu:sphere` is called.

However, the textures never appear - objects are rendered in flat colors.

I went through several OpenGL guides and I do not think I am missing a step, but who knows.

Here is what is roughly happening:

- call `gl:enable :texture-2d` to turn on textures
- load images using `cl-jpeg`
- call `gl:bind-texture`
- copy data from image using `gl:tex-image-2d`
- generate texture ids with `gl:gen-textures`. Also tried generating ids one by one instead of all at once, which had no effect.
- during drawing create new quadric, enable texture coordinates generation and bind the texture before generating the quadric points:

```cl
    (let ((q (glu:new-quadric)))
      (if (planet-state-texture-id ps)
          (progn (gl:enable :texture-gen-s)
                 (gl:enable :texture-gen-t)
                 (glu:quadric-texture q :true)
                 (gl:bind-texture :texture-2d planet-texture-id)))
        (glu:quadric-texture q :false))
      (glu:sphere q
                  planet-diameter
                  *sphere-resolution*
                  *sphere-resolution*)
```

I also tried a more manual method of texture coordinates generation, which had no effect.

Out of ideas here…

- [make-texture](https://github.com/monomon/planetarium/blob/7090b78dcd12df9dc3337964d90c1b0e8c3ab1ca/planetarium.lisp#L205) function
- [texture id generation](https://github.com/monomon/planetarium/blob/7090b78dcd12df9dc3337964d90c1b0e8c3ab1ca/planetarium.lisp#L189)
- [quadric drawing](https://github.com/monomon/planetarium/blob/7090b78dcd12df9dc3337964d90c1b0e8c3ab1ca/planetarium.lisp#L335)

When the program runs, I can see the textures are loaded and texture ids are reserved, it prints

```lisp
loading texture from textures/2k_neptune.jpg with id 1919249769
Loaded data. Image dimensions: 1024x2048
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you've discovered a solution to your problem, but after creating a test image, and modifying some of your code, I was able to get the texture to be applied to the sphere.

The problem comes into play with the fact that you are attempting to upload textures to the GPU before you've enabled them.  (gl:enable :texture-2d) has to be called before you start handling texture/image data.
I'd recommend putting the let* block with the planets-init that is in the main function after 'setup-gl', and also moving the 'format' function with the planets data to work correctly without an error coming up.
My recommendation is something like:

```
(let ((camera ...
   ...
  (setup-gl ...)
  (let* ((planets...
    ...
    (format ... planet-state)
```

In your draw-planet function, you'll want to add (gl:bind-texture :texture-2d 0) at the end of it so that the texture isn't used for another object, like the orbital path.
As is, the (gl:color 1.0 ...) before the (gl:quadratic-texture ...) will modify the color of the rendered object, so it may not look like what you're expecting it to look like.

Edit: I should've clarified this, but as your code stands it goes

```
initialize-planets > make-textures > enable-textures > render
```

When it should be

```
enable-textures > init-planets > make-textures > render
```

You're correct about not missing a step, the steps in your code are just misordered.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for diving into this! There are still some issues, but the textures appear. Any idea why an error is not signalled when doing stuff like reserving textures without an initialized gl context? Is it just "fault tolerance"?

Comment: One interesting thing is that texture ids are now sequential integers, they were all over the place when `enable-textures` hadn't been called.

Comment: Updated on github, also

Comment: Apologies for getting back to you so late, but it's somewhat complicated, while Opengl does signal an error, this has to be retrieved with a function, in particular `gl:get-error` in cl-opengl. From what I read, `get-error` has to be called after each possible problematic gl call, that is if the error isn't caught by the cl-opengl implementation (I think).
The reason why GL doesn't quit or signal an error in the traditional sense is so that it doesn't bring down the rest of the system.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'll try using gl:get-error in some places that might fail.